# repeating a jquery click activated animation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have scoured the internet for over a day and had no hope so I present you with my issue:

I have tried using .toggle() and if/else statements but struggled to implement the window_width, element_width and edge dimensions that are implemented into the below JS.

In the code below -

I have a blue and green span that individually animate the red parent span to the edges of the browser window, the green goes to the far right and the blue to the far left. Now this works fine until I try and repeat the process. So say I go left and then right...I can no longer go left, and vice versa. My question is how can I make this animation work indefinitely so I can constantly switch between the left and right hand sides of the browser window?

Like to thank everyone in advance for helping me out. Greatest appreciation. Cheers

JS-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#two').click(function(){
window_width = $(document).width();
element_width = $('#one').width();
edge = window_width - element_width;
$('#one').animate({right:edge}, 2000).delay(1000);
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#three').click(function(){
window_width = $(document).width();
element_width = $('#one').width();
edge = window_width - element_width;
$('#one').animate({left:edge}, 2000).delay(1000);
});
});
```

HTML-

```
<span id='one'>&nbsp;    
<span id='two'>&nbsp;</span>
<span id='three'>&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

CSS-

```
#one {
    height:100px;
    width:210px;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
#two {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
#three {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:green;
    float:right;
}
```

If at all interested about it's purpose and how it will be implemented into a site - the blue (#two) and green (#three) spans will be used as buttons for two halves of a website, when selected which half you wish to view the buttons move aside to reveal the appropriate content for that half. Once to the side if the viewer selects the other button then the current content disappears whilst the buttons move to the other side of the browser, once stationed to the other side the new (other half) content appears.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Answer (score 0):

it will work if you write in the #two click handler:

```
$('#one').animate({right:edge, left:0}, 2000).delay(1000);
```

and in the #three click handler:

```
$('#one').animate({left:edge, right:0}, 2000).delay(1000);
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mejSb/6/)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much. You saved me many more hours of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you animate the left property while you've set the right property of the div in the css to 0.

I would do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/58sQA/1/

```
    #one {
        .... 
        //replace right: 0 with
        left: 200px; //set this to the width of the container minus the width of #one
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#two').click(function(){            
            $('#one').animate({            
                left: 0
            }, 2000);
        });
        $('#three').click(function(){        
            $('#one').animate({            
                left: 200 //200 should match the value in css
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
```